# DJango Python deployment on Heroku stopped working

Tags: python, django, heroku

We have django based python 3.7 version application was running properly on heroku but suddenly since 2 week all new deployment fails with following error. Its working on my local machine with runserver command.

Here is errors logs for more reference. please help me as my prod app needs new changes to deployed and now everything is blocked.

> Updated Pipfile.lock (599d25)!
> Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (599d25)…
> To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
> Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
> Removing intermediate container 2125752d2f35
> ---> a3b53b037080
> Step 10/11 : RUN pipenv install --system
> ---> Running in fcb5350323a4
> Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (599d25)…
> An error occurred while installing importlib-metadata==4.10.0 ; python_version < '3.8' --hash=sha256:92a8b58ce734b2a4494878e0ecf7d79ccd7a128b5fc6014c401e0b61f006f0f6 --hash=sha256:b7cf7d3fef75f1e4c80a96ca660efbd51473d7e8f39b5ab9210febc7809012a4! Will try again.
> An error occurred while installing zipp==3.7.0 --hash=sha256:9f50f446828eb9d45b267433fd3e9da8d801f614129124863f9c51ebceafb87d --hash=sha256:b47250dd24f92b7dd6a0a8fc5244da14608f3ca90a5efcd37a3b1642fac9a375! Will try again.
> Installing initially failed dependencies…
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 254, in install
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1874, in do_install
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1253, in do_init
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 862, in do_install_dependencies
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, False, failed_deps_queue, retry=False)
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Collecting importlib-metadata==4.10.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-01ok21hj-requirements/pipenv-lkap3a1h-requirement.txt (line 1))']
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement importlib-metadata==4.10.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-01ok21hj-requirements/pipenv-lkap3a1h-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.7.0, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.2.0, 3.3.0, 3.4.0, 3.5.0, 3.6.0, 3.7.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.2, 3.7.3, 3.8.0, 3.8.1, 3.8.2, 3.9.0, 3.9.1, 3.10.0, 3.10.1, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.4.0, 4.5.0, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.6.3, 4.6.4, 4.7.0, 4.7.1, 4.8.0, 4.8.1, 4.8.2, 4.8.3)', 'No matching distribution found for importlib-metadata==4.10.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-01ok21hj-requirements/pipenv-lkap3a1h-requirement.txt (line 1))']
> ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
> The command '/bin/sh -c pipenv install --system' returned a non-zero code: 1

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting the requirements from `pipenv` into `requirements.txt` file and try to get the requirements from the `.txt` file instead of pipenv?